Download PDF invoice from PayPal API
I want to generate/download PayPal invoice using the PayPal API, but I didn't find any way for this in documentation. Does anybody know how do this, or know any nodejs package which help me generate a PDF using paypal invoice details?

PayPal only generates invoice links or sends them via email. There is no PDF functionality. The best you could do is generate a PDF yourself and include a PayPal invoice link in it to open on the web, although it would be somewhat redundant.
